# Document.Ready in Script#

Tags: c#, script#

What is the [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/) syntax for getting the following output javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //..my code
});
```

I have tried `jQuery.OnDocumentReady` but that has two problems:

(1) It can only be called from inside a function (defeats the purpose since it won't get called on startup)
(2) <del>It generates the following code, which is not quite right:</del> Edit: My mistake, these are equivalent

```
$(function() {
    //..my code
});
```

Comment: Actually, those two code samples are identical.

Comment: TIL! I will edit out that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp-Getting-Started.aspx):

> In script#, static constructors get generated as code that runs
>   immediately as the script is loaded and parsed

So the code ended up looking like this:

```
[GlobalMethods]
static class Main
{
   static Main()
   {
      jQuery.OnDocumentReady(new Action(delegate()
      {
         //..my code
      }));
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what the jQuery Page item template gives you when you select it in the File | Add Item dialog.